# avoid duplicate in php sql

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a page which displays set of data from mysql.

I wanted to know is there any way to avoid displaying a data with same name?

for example if i have 2 skills in database as PHP and php then it should only display either one of those .

Comment: Please share your table structure, some sample data and the result you want to get.

Comment: Please read [The tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use group by in your SQL query to group the skills and appear only one.

If the column name is **`skill`** append the following line to the query

```
GROUP BY LOWER(skill);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` keyword.

e.g `SELECT DISTINCT skill FROM skills`

Database is case-insenstive (at least MySQL), so `php` and `PHP` will be treated as duplicates.

Hence, the problem gets solved.

Comment: select distinct is not working it produces result to my auto populate . is there any other way?

Comment: DISTINCT should produce non-duplicate results. Please check your query once again.

Comment: query is select distinct name from skill

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Why do you think this would answer the question? Please add a proper description.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM skills
```

DISTINCT keyword is used to return only distinct (different) values.